# Authentication between two (multiple) laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am building complex ERP system with laravel as REST API and decided to dived it into modules. By modules I mean separate laravel projects.

I have question how to authenticate transactions between modules/projects?

**For Example**:main app which controller authentication. And if request is properly authenticated main app sends request to another app. I need proper authentication between apps in order to prevent unauthorized access as both apps works with APIs.

Comment: Do you mean a user can authenticate at both systems? Or how the two systems can work with each other?

Comment: I have added an example for this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing algorism is good and secure.

You need to compute a hash of all your parameters and pass that hash along with parameters to the server.
Hash will be calculated using a secret SALT key, input parameters, and hashing algorism

For Eg, if you are using sha512 algorithm

```
hash("sha512", $hash_data)
```

Here the string $hash_data is created using your sorted input parameters (separated by ' : | etc..) and secret SALT key

You need to pass this generated hash along with your input parameters

On the other hand, after receiving request you need to generate hash again with input parameters (without including hash which you passed in the request) using the same method and compare both the hash strings

[This link explains how to generate a hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)